# How to properly configure Cygnus?

Tags: flume, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I was playing a bit with Cygnus, and I was wondering how to properly configure it. I’ve seen both `agent_<id>.conf` and `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf` files are needed. I understand the purpose of the first one, but not the second one. In addition, what about the `grouping_rules.conf` file? Is there any other configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File by file:

- `agent_<id>.conf` file is the main configuration file for Cygnus. It inherits the syntax from Apache Flume, the base technology used by Cygnus, thus it is used to declare and specify the sources, channels and sinks of your Cygnus agent.
- `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf` file is used to configure other Cygnus parameters that cannot be configured as part of the agent configuration, such as the logging file, the management interface port, etc. Cygnus service will run as many instances as `cygnus_instance_<id>.conf` files are configured. That's why an `<id>` must be provided, since this `<id>` will be used to find the proper `agent_<id>.conf` file.
- `grouping_rules.conf` file is used when the [Grouping Rules](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/flume_extensions_catalogue/grouping_interceptor.md) advanced feature is wanted to be used. Usually, this file may be empty (but it must exist) and Cygnus will run after all.
- `flume-env.sh` file has been inherited from Apache Flume, and it is used in order to configure certain Flume paramters such as the classpath overwritting the default one, some Java options (`-Xms`, `-Xmx`, etc)...